# How to reverse voltage 12-24VDC to use a peltier element for heating and cooling

Tags: power, mosfet, relay, peltier

I'd like to use a standard peltier element as a heater and a cooler. The specs should be something around 12VDC, 30W. Electromechanical relays are not an option, the peltier should be used to regulate a temperature for many months. The hardware should be designed to withstand switching several times per minute.

The answer of @tobalt helped me. I'll simply use a [H-Bridge, as you can find here on amazon](https://www.amazon.de/Motorantriebsmodul-Schrittmotortreiber-Motortreiber-Motorantriebs-Steuerplatine-Schrittmotor/dp/B08JGRHW8W/ref=sr_1_3_sspa?crid=154W2V6K94530&keywords=h%20br%C3%BCcke&qid=1650884048&sprefix=h%20br%C3%BCcke%2Caps%2C117&sr=8-3-spons&psc=1&smid=AH8VKKOH0D80&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExODNVTFVTV1Q2SUIwJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUExMDI2MDg5MkFESFQzNlNaN0NBUSZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNTg4NzQ2MUVRRFY3MU81MExXUyZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=). I knew those H-Bridges from controlling stepper motors but these are also exactly what I need to control Peltier-Elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build an H-Bridge switching at >20 kHz, ideally >100 kHz. Pass the output through LC lowpass filtering. This will create a smooth DC current through the Peltiert, which can flow in both directions (hear or cool).

You can control the bridge duty cycle in a feedback loop to stabilize a certain temperature. For this you need a temperature sensor reading the Peltier temperature obviously.

Comment: You don't need an LC filter or fast switching if you don't want to use PWM. (But maybe PWM is a good idea)

Comment: @user253751 Running a Peltier e.g. constantly at 5 A is more efficient than running it at 10 A with a 50% duty cycle. That means, you get less waste heat with the DC current. It is strongly recommended to use a DC current whenever you don't have full power, as opposed to a PWM current waveform.